# How to show a different object from array in my Aurelia HTML?

Tags: typescript, data-binding, binding, aurelia

Afternoon everyone,

New to Aurelia and I'm having some trouble binding a different card to show when I click my link

We are using Aurelia.

This is my html.

```
 <div repeat.for="card of cards" class="dilemmacards-detail">  
    <p repeat.for="paragraph of card.textSituation" model.bind="paragraph">${paragraph}</p>
 </div>
<div click.trigger="getRandomCard()">Random card</div>
```

I've skinned this down for reading purposes of course.

This is being used to fill the cards.

```
 public activate(args?: IDilemmaCardsArguments): void {
    const RADIX: number = 10;
    const id: number = parseInt(((args as IDilemmaCardsArguments).id as string), RADIX);
    this.cards = this._dillemaCardManager.getCardsByDeckId(id);
    this.logo = this._dillemaCardManager.getLogoByDeckId(id);

  }
```

I have a link in the html which generates a random number there getting a different card.

```
public getRandomCard()
{
   card = this.cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.cards.length)];
  //ToDO perhaps eventually return a different card 
}
```

My questions:

**1.  Do I have to refactor this and just have it return a single card (in other words remove the array for example).**

**2.  What is the best way to go about this?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to remove the array and just use a single card. 
Works and is less code.